# Can the kube-vip load balancing service implement jumps after a kubernetes node is notReady?

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes, high-availability, virtual-ip

I'm new to kubernetes and I'm learning about high availability clustering, I'm using kube-vip for load balancing in the form of static pods.

```
# kubeadm version
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"27", GitVersion:"v1.27.3", GitCommit:"25b4e43193bcda6c7328a6d147b1fb73a33f1598", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-06-14T09:52:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Satatic pod manifest
kube-vip.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: kube-vip
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - manager
    env:
    - name: vip_arp
      value: "true"
    - name: port
      value: "6443"
    - name: vip_interface
      value: ens33
    - name: vip_cidr
      value: "32"
    - name: cp_enable
      value: "true"
    - name: cp_namespace
      value: kube-system
    - name: vip_ddns
      value: "false"
    - name: svc_enable
      value: "true"
    - name: svc_leasename
      value: plndr-svcs-lock
    - name: vip_leaderelection
      value: "true"
    - name: vip_leasename
      value: plndr-cp-lock
    - name: vip_leaseduration
      value: "5"
    - name: vip_renewdeadline
      value: "3"
    - name: vip_retryperiod
      value: "1"
    - name: address
      value: 192.168.44.100
    - name: prometheus_server
      value: :2112
    image: ghcr.io/kube-vip/kube-vip:v0.6.3
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: kube-vip
    resources: {}
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        add:
        - NET_ADMIN
        - NET_RAW
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
      name: kubeconfig
  hostAliases:
  - hostnames:
    - kubernetes
    ip: 127.0.0.1
  hostNetwork: true
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
    name: kubeconfig
status: {}
```

I try to close the kubelet of the node where the virtual ip is located, the virtual ip doesn't jump to another node; but when I close the network of the node or just shutdown, the virtual ip jumps on its own.

I would like to implement a feature that allows the virtual ip to jump to another node when the node it is on is notReady. Is it possible to realize this function?

Looking forward to your help!